# Aggregate column from child data set in parent data set

Tags: birt

There is a column Total cost which is sum of line cost present in the child data set. I would like to perform Sum of (Total Cost) in the parent data set as there will many total cost present in child data set.

I have tried to perform aggregation however the fields present in child data set are not appearing in the main table.

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I do is to create a general variable in the main report in Scripts

Script on the report layout - > that contains something like:

```
var a = 0;
```

Than on the result of each (total) yellow results please double click and please put a formula like in each table you would add an expression before your total that would be like:

```
a = a + dataSetRow["Total"];
```

At the end on the total of Totals you will put in expressions only:

```
a
```

without the semicolon in order to print the value of the variable.

Comment: E.Flores Delfin I assume the variable should be declared in the initialize . Where should I add the expression a = a + dataSetRow["Total"]; ? In the child data set where the aggregation is done on the layout ?

Comment: Ok, the var = 0; I reccomend on the initialization of the report itself it means click on the layout of the report out of any other object then on Script tab go and put that variable. The formula of the a = a + a = a + dataSetRow["Total"]; should be in the field for dynamic data when yo're printing the info, then on the other total of totals that you have would have only to print the a to show the result of the sums that it do.

Comment: E.Flores Delfin Please refer the attached image. I have entered the the formula a = dataSetRow["Total"] at the field highlighted in YELLOW only then the sum of total cost appears correctly ( for example - 18866.97) . At the end of the column I have used aggregation of RUNNINGSUM of "a" but it displays 0.

Comment: You will use the next, on each yellow cell you will add the formula a = a + (the field that is the result of the sum)

then on the sum of total costo you will just put a.

Comment: E. Flores Delfin It doesn't work. I do not see a way to attach the report design file here. Please note that I'm performing the sum of linecost using aggregation . Hence the field highlighted in YELLOW has an aggregation on row[linecost] which I'm storing in a and then using a in the parent dataset which displays 0.